# Confusion: Normal homomorphism vs. weak*-continuous vs $\sigma$-weakly continuous

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, terminology

$\newcommand\M{\mathcal M}
\newcommand\N{\mathcal N}
\newcommand\A{\mathcal A}
\newcommand\B{\mathcal B}$
In Takesaki [1], I find the following theorem:

> **Proposition 5.13.** Let $\M_1,\M_2,\N_1,\N_2$ be von Neumann algebras. If $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are $\sigma$-weakly continuous completely positive maps of $\M_1$ into $\N_1$ and $\M_2$ into $\N_2$, respectively, then there exists a $\sigma$-weakly continuous completely positive map $\theta$ of $\M_1\overline\otimes\M_2$ into $\N_1\overline\otimes\N_2$ such that $$\theta(x_1\otimes x_2)=\theta_1(x_1)\otimes \theta_2(x_2),
> \qquad x_1\in\M_1,\qquad x_2\in\M_2.$$

($\overline\otimes$ denotes the tensor product of von Neumann algebras here.)

Moreover, in Conway [2], I find:

> **46.5 Corollary.** If $\A$ and $\B$ are von Neumann algebras and $\rho:\A\to\B$ is a positive linear map, then $\rho$ is normal if and only if it is weak* continuous.

Conway also mentions in §20 that weak* in Conway's language is called $\sigma$-weak by some other authors. So "$\sigma$-weakly continuous" in Takesaki's theorem is the same as "weak*-continuous" in Conway's theorem. Hence "$\sigma$-weakly continuous" can be replaced by "normal" in Takesaki's theorem.

**My question:** Why does it say "$\sigma$-weakly continuous" in Takesaki's theorem and not "normal"? Is there some good reason for this (e.g., some distinction between the terms that I misunderstood)? Takesaki does use the term normal in many other theorems. Is there some convention by which the different terms are used in different contexts? Do I read the theorem wrong?

(I want to use the theorem in the "normal" case but I am afraid that there is some misunderstanding.)

[1] *Takesaki, M.*, Theory of operator algebras I., Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences 124. Operator Algebras and Non-Commutative Geometry 5. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-42248-X/hbk). xix, 415 p. (2002). [ZBL0990.46034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0990.46034).

[2] *Conway, John B.*, A course in operator theory, Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 21. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xv, 372 p. (2000). [ZBL0936.47001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0936.47001).

Comment: Perhaps (I haven't closely checked) Takesaki uses the word "normal" only for functionals and *-homomorphisms, and "$\sigma$-weakly continuous" for more general maps (such as CP maps here).

Comment: @MatthewDaws No, doesn't seem so. I found various occurrences of "normal representation" in Takesaki (and I don't think they are representation with target $\mathbb C$). And I just found "Definition 2.15. A uniformly continuous linear map $\pi$ of a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal M$ into another von Neumann algebra $\mathcal N$ is called normal if $\pi$ is $\sigma$-weakly continuous." So the only restriction is that the term does not apply for functions that are not uniformly continuous. But since the theorem in question talks about completely positive maps which are always uniformly continuous

Comment: that can't be the reason. By the way: of course we probably cannot for sure find out what Takesaki's intent was (unless Takesaki happens to be on Mathoverflow, of course :) ), so I would also settle for some confirmation by people who know the area well that Takesaki's theorem holds for the usual notion of "normal" and that I am the victim of some terminology-mixup. (Normal is one of the most dangerous words in that respect! :) )

Comment: Right, I stand corrected!  Btw, I would say that "normal" is a synonym for "weak$^*$-continuous" which means $\sigma$-weakly continuous.  But my opinion is not really an answer...

Comment: The only difference that occasionally pops up is that some authors display a preference to use “normal” for positive (or order-preserving) maps, since normality is often defined as preservation of suprema.  This convention is not used by all authors, though.  Otherwise the terms are synonymous.  For an example of such usage, see Definition 1.13.1 and Theorem 1.13.2 in Sakai's _C\*-algebras and W\*-algebras_.